# Unity RigidBody2d pass through

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a scene with 2 objects which are the base (has Box2dCollider) and the paddle (has RigidBody2D and Box2DCollider). However, the paddle keeps passing through the base without stopping moving. What could go wrong with my setup?

Answer (score 0):

Turning off the isTrigger in Box2DCollider will solve my problem.